# laravel - Pikaday is not defined in blade-ui-kit

Tags: laravel-8

I am using the backage [blade-ui-kit](https://blade-ui-kit.com/docs/0.x/introduction) in laravel .. the components works fine except the `pickday` component .. it gives me an error and did not work ... when i click on it the calendar opened but the error repeated forever .. and the app hanging

Laravel: 8.54

blade-ui-kit: 0.3.1

----- app.blade.php -----

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

  @livewireStyles

  @bukStyles
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased" id="app">
    <main>
      {{ $slot }}
    </main>
  @livewireScripts

  @bukScripts
</body>
</html>
```

----- create.blade.php -----

```php
<x-app-layout>

  <div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
        <div class="p-4">
          <x-form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" has-files>
            @csrf
            <div class="space-y-6">

              <div>
                <x-trix name="about" />
              </div>

              <div>
                <x-pikaday name="published_at" />
              </div>

              <x-jet-button>
                {{ __('Create') }}
              </x-jet-button>

            </div>
          </x-form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

both `x-form` and `x-trix` works fine

but when i used `<x-pikaday name="published_at" />` it gives me an error in the console and did not work

```js
dispatch.js:6 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at dispatch (dispatch.js:6)
    at Livewire.value (index.js:87)
    at create:365
    at dispatch (app.js:1803)
    at Object.start (app.js:1858)
    at alpine.js:1696
    at create:357
    at dispatch (dispatch.js:6)
    at Livewire.value (index.js:87)
    at create:365
```